# Debugging OpenFX plugins

Tags: video-processing, video-editing, visual-effects, openfx

I am creating a visual effects plug-in using OpenFX.

I have followed [the programming guides from the official documentation](https://github.com/ofxa/openfx/blob/master/Guide/Doc/ofxProgrammingGuide.adoc).
However, I didn't find anything relating to debugging of OpenFX plugins.

I am looking for some specific methods for debugging my plug-in. I am currently using [Natron](https://github.com/MrKepzie/Natron) / [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/davinciresolve) as host applications.

Currently I have tried (I am running on Mac) to ``Attach to process'' via lldb or Xcode to e.g. DaVinci Resolve. Both results in an error or lost connection.

Comment: Did you solved the issue with debugging Resolve? I have the same issue: cannot attach debugger to it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your IDE. With Visual Studio, for example, in your Solution used to build your plug-in you can set the "executable to run" as the host application. Then when you debug your plug-in, it will launch the host application under the debugger. Once the host has loaded your plug-in, your breakpoints become active (and new ones can be set) and will be hit when the host makes calls into your plug-in. You'll get source level debugging for your plug-in, but unless you have symbols the host items in the stack trace will just be hex.

Edit: I just noticed you said you're on a Mac. In Xcode, edit your Scheme. In Run/Debug you can set the Executable. As above, pick the host application. When you tell Xcode to "Run" your plug-in, it should launch the host.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, currently I have no luck with debugging the application in the Xcode by setting the Executable in the Scheme. I guess this is not possible with all applications?